# UIPath get current file name

Tags: uipath

While running *mail.xaml*, how could I find the current running *Xaml* file name dynamically?

In other words, get the Main.xaml name dynamically in the flow. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Don’t think it can be done.
But one thing you might consider is storing all the .xaml filepaths that you wish to invoke into variables or an array, then you can use that in your Invoke Workflow to call it and you can tell which part of the process you are currently at.

You can also use System.Environment.CurrentDirectory (or Directory.GetCurrentDirectory) and Directory.GetFiles() to gather the .xamls located in the folder. And, if your filenames are named where they are in the order of the process, you can store them into a list and use that list in your Invokes.

Another tip is you can get the filename only by using Path.GetFileName(), but requires a full path I think. Or you can also use a .Split like filepathvariable.Split("\"c).Last